# Почему программа работает некорректно? Как правильно записать условие?

Tags: c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

double x, y, R;
int main(void)
{
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
printf("Введите x, y:\n");
scanf("%lf%lf", &x, &y);
R = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
if(((x >= -7) && (y >= 0) && (x <= 7) && (y <= 7)) || (R <= 3.5))
{
    printf("Точка принадлежит заданной области\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Точка не принадлежит заданной области\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

При в воде x = 1, y = -3 выдает неправильный результат: "Точка не принадлежит заданной области". Хотя R = 3.1 что меньше 3.5 и предполагается ответ "Точка принадлежит заданной области", в чем проблема?

Comment: А почему вы не пользуетесь отладчиком? Вы хотите, чтобы мы сделали это за вас?

Comment: @Леонид Я не могу воспроизвести ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не хватает

```
#include <math.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Константа с плавающей точкой указано неверно. Не `3,5` надо, а `3.5`.

Comment: Там стоит точка

Comment: Была запятая. Исправили уже.